# C++: Dates and octal constants

Tags: c++

So my problem right now is when I compile my code I get the error "invalid digit in octal constant", when I try to parse in the Year value "08" for one of my Date objects. Apparently the reason this is happening is because it's a hexadecimal or something. Right now I have the Year variable stored as an int type, so what would be the best datatype to store the Year variable as, in order to prevent this error from happening?

And before you ask, no, I cannot store the Year variable as four digits (ie. "2008") rather than two digits (ie. "08), because the file that I need read input data from at the moment has the Year stored as two digits.

Comment: The compiler is *surely* not reading from a file (apart from the source file which you typed in)

Answer (score 1):

Any literal that starts with `0` is interpreted as octal, and octal `8` doesn't make sense (valid digits are `0` through `7`). That'd be like having `0xG`. In base 8, the symbol `8` doesn't make sense, just like in base 16, `G` doesn't.

Just store it as `8`.

The value should be decouple from the representation. If you want to display it as `08`, that's fine, but you should store it as `8` (assuming `2008` is out of the question).

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the file that I am reading from has the year stored with a 0 in front of it, for example: 13/06/08. In this case, how can I read store the year value when there's a zero in front of it?

Comment: @user2742003 you can read the `0` from the file just fine, no need to store it.

Comment: @user2742003 how are you reading it? Please provide some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok lemme give u an example from the file "customers.txt":

C0001 George I. Bullock 1295 Donec St. Limena 9545 14/07/13 3548.17

Each piece of data is tab delimited, and I need to read the customer details from the file and store them inside a vector (eg. vector <Customer> cList)

The data is as folows:

id<tab>name<tab>address<tab>city<tab>postcode<tab>date_account_due<tab>amountowed

Now I want to be able to store the date portion using the constructor:

Date(int day, int month, int year)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Integers beginning with `0` are octal. For instance `010` is the same as decimal `8`. But `08` is invalid because `8` is not a valid octal digit.

If you need to use it as an integer, use `8` instead. There are more than one way to output `8` as two digits, or store input two-digit number.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent the compiler from regarding your year as octal (and then complaining if it is too big for base 8) is to avoid writing

```
const int year = 08;
```

but write

```
const int year = 8;
```

instead. The `0` prefix means octal.